# My panel not showing in Smart GWT

Tags: gwt, smartgwt, gxt

I am trying to add a GXT panel to my smartGWT tab panel but it is not showing.i get this error.i have done this in another tab and it is working but in in my second tab. when i select the second tab i see blank page and in the console i have this error.

Uncaught JavaScript exception [uncaught exception: java.lang.AssertionError: A widget that has an existing parent widget may not be added to the detach list] in , line 0

here is my code

```
VLayout formBtnFrm = new VLayout();
    formBtnFrm.addMember(addEditForm);// addEditForm is DynamicForm

    HLayout buttonLayout = new HLayout();
    buttonLayout.setMembersMargin(10);
    buttonLayout.setHeight(22);

    buttonLayout.addMember(createUser);
    buttonLayout.addMember(editUser);
    buttonLayout.setLayoutAlign(Alignment.CENTER);

    formBtnFrm.addMember(buttonLayout);

    ContentPanel panel = new ContentPanel();
    panel.setFrame(true);
    panel.setCollapsible(false);
    panel.setAnimCollapse(false);
    panel.setButtonAlign(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
    panel.setHeading("Registration Form");
    panel.setLayout(new FitLayout());
    panel.add(formBtnFrm);
    panel.setSize(350, 250);

    groupLayout.addMember(panel);
    mainLayout.addMember(groupGrid);
    mainLayout.addMember(groupLayout);
    addMember(mainLayout);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is not recommended at all to mix (for example gwt and smartgwt) I guess it's same thing with Gxt widgets by expérience (with gwt mix) even if it happen to work you never know when you will have a crazy behavior..;

Answer (score 0):

You can always mix GWT widgets with those of Smartgwt, but not Smartgwt and gxt. Chances are many that things might not workout as expected because these are on the same level, they are are all bulit on top of gwt. Meaning the two venders might not have concentrated on making their widgets feet into each other.